# Tk window randomly opening along with CTkInputDialog

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

For this code:

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter

ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
dialog = ctk.CTkInputDialog(text="Type in a number:", title="Test")
print("Number:", dialog.get_input())
```

The desirable output is CtkInputDialog Box which asks me the number and prints it in the console. However while running the code. A Tkinter Windows opens alongside. It cannot be closed and closes automatically when CtkInputDialog Box is closed or the code finishes execution. This code is from the Ctk documentations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every tkinter application requires a root window. If you don't create one explicitly then one will be created the first time you create any other widget.

In this case, you aren't creating a root window so one is being created for you.

You should explicitly create a root window. If you don't want it to be visible you can hide it.

```
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter

root = ctk.CTk()
root.withdraw()
ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
dialog = ctk.CTkInputDialog(text="Type in a number:", title="Test")
print("Number:", dialog.get_input())
```